# How can i update the date? it gets stuck on the date when i ran the app

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to update the Date each day, right now it gets stuck on the Date when i opened the app, when i open it says for example: Sunday 22 February 2015, and tomorrow it will keep showing Sunday 22 February 2015 instead of Monday 23 February 2015.

**The JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]; 
var dayNames["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
var newDate = new Date();

newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());

$('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());

setInterval( function() {
var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
$("#sec").html(( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds);
},1000);

setInterval( function() {
var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
$("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
},1000);

setInterval( function() {
var hours = new Date().getHours();
$("#hours").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
}, 1000);
});
```

to load on:

```
<div id="Date"></div>
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="min"></div>
<div id="sec"></div>
```

working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/679wjmkm/)

Comment: What you did for `hours`, `min` and `sec`, do it for `Date` as well...

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need 3 different intervals.

Just put the date inside the interval and you'll be set. Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/679wjmkm/2/

```
setInterval( function() {
    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    $("#sec").html(( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds);
        var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    $("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
        var hours = new Date().getHours();
    $("#hours").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
    var date = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
    $('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and write something like `moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');` or 
`moment().format('LLLL')` that will give you `Sunday, February 22, 2015 6:11 PM`, updated in real time.

Moment was especially written to avoid developers messing up with dates and pulling their hair out.

In case you can't or don't want to use Moment, do as Miro said (at least don't set 3 intervals when one is enough :)

Comment: plus 1 for simplicity and for using things that have already been done :)